# Converting typed JavaRDD to Row JavaRDD

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I am trying to **convert a typed rdd** to row rdd and then creating the **dataframe** from it. It **throws exception** when I execute code.

code:

```
JavaRDD<Counter> rdd = sc.parallelize(counters);
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = rdd.map((Function<Counter, Row>) RowFactory::create);

//I am using some schema here based on the class Counter
DataFrame df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, getSchema());
marineDF.show(); //throws Exception
```

Does conversion from typed rdd to row rdd preserve the order in the row factory? If not how do I make sure of that?

Class code :

```
class Counter {
  long vid;
  byet[] bytes; 
  List<B> blist;
}
class B {
  String id;
  long count;
}
```

schema:

```
private StructType getSchema() {
List<StructField> fields = new ArrayList<>();
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("vid", DataTypes.LongType, false));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("bytes",DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.ByteType), false));

List<StructField> bFields = new ArrayList<>();
bFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, false));
bFields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("count", DataTypes.LongType, false));

StructType bclasSchema = DataTypes.createStructType(bFields);

fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("blist", DataTypes.createArrayType(bclasSchema, false), false));
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);
return schema;
}
```

fails with exception :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: test.spark.SampleTest$A cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

    at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToLong(BoxesRunTime.java:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.BaseGenericInternalRow$class.getLong(rows.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericInternalRow.getLong(rows.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$LongConverter$.toScalaImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:367)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is there is no conversion here. When you create a `Row` it can accept an arbitrary `Object`. It is placed as is. So it is not equivalent to a `DataFrame` creation:

```java
spark.createDataFrame(rdd, Counter.class);
```

or a `Dataset<Counter>` creation:

```java
Encoder<Counter> encoder = Encoders.bean(Counter.class);
spark.createDataset(rdd, encoder);
```

when working with bean classes.

So `RowFactory::create` is just not applicable here. If you want to pass `RDD<Row>` all values should be already represented in a form that can be directly used with `DataFrame` with [required type mapping](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types). It means you have to explicitly map each `Counter` to `Row` of the following shape:

```java
Row(vid, bytes, List(Row(id1, count1), ..., Row(idN, countN))
```

and your code should be equivalent to:

```java
JavaRDD<Row> rows = counters.map((Function<Counter, Row>) cnt -> {
  return RowFactory.create(
    cnt.vid, cnt.bytes,
    cnt.blist.stream().map(b -> RowFactory.create(b.id, b.count)).toArray()
  );
});

Dataset<Row> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, getSchema());
```